# How can I bind output values to my async Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, azure-functions

How can I bind my outputs to an async function?  The usual method of setting the parameter to `out` doesn't work with async functions.

#### Example

```
using System;

public static async void Run(string input, TraceWriter log, out string blobOutput)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");
    await Task.Delay(1);

    blobOutput = input;
}
```

This results in a compilation Error:

```
[timestamp] (3,72): error CS1988: Async methods cannot have ref or out parameters
```

Binding used (fyi)

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "blobOutput",
      "path": "testoutput/{rand-guid}.txt",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "manualTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this:

### Bind the output to the function's return value (Easiest)

Then you can simply return the value from your function.  You'll have to set the output binding's name to `$return` in order to use this method

#### Code

```
public static async Task<string> Run(string input, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");
    await Task.Delay(1);

    return input;
}
```

#### Binding

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "$return",
      "path": "testoutput/{rand-guid}.txt",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "manualTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

### Bind the output to IAsyncCollector

Bind the output to IAsyncCollector and add your item to the collector.

You'll want to use this method when you have more than one output bindings.

#### Code

```
public static async Task Run(string input, IAsyncCollector<string> collection, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");
    await collection.AddAsync(input);
}
```

#### Binding

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "collection",
      "path": "testoutput/{rand-guid}.txt",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "manualTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: I have an issue when I use : `ICollectorAsync` : `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICollectorAsync<>' could not be found`

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond sorry, that should have been IAsyncCollector

Comment: Collectors are not supported for Blob output bindings, see this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/162). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44672091/1171619) for another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Async methods can return values normally, but you shouldn't return the pure type of value, use Task instead, like this:

```
 public static async Task<string> Run(string input, TraceWriter log, string blobOutput)
    {
        log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");
        await Task.Delay(1);

        blobOutput = input;
        return blobOutput;
    }
```

Comment: Doh! Yeah,  I had meant to set the return value to Task<string>.  The function from my original answer prob wouldn't even work. Thanks, I've fixed it now

Comment: Don't forget that this also requires you to set the "name" property in your function.json to "$return" for your output binding.  This tells the runtime to use the output of your function as the source.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the reputation yet to be able to make a comment, but in Zain Rizvi's code above, it should say IAsyncCollector:

```
public static async Task Run(string input, IAsyncCollector<string> collection, 
TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {input}");
    await collection.AddAsync(input);
}
```

Comment: iasyncollector is not supported for blobs