# Azure function documentdb out parameters error

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

How do I use docuementdb binding with azure function http binding:

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, out object locationDocument, TraceWriter log){
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    var data = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"{data}");
}
```

Getting this error:

```
error CS1988: Async methods cannot have ref or out parameters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to Document DB. If your function is async, and you already used the return value for HTTP output binding, you would need to inject `IAsyncCollector<T>` for all other output bindings.

See the second example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40409345/1171619).