# send an email from azure functions when a process finishes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a device that sends data in text form  to a blob on AZURE, once the blob receives the data it triggers a function in azure functions which is basically and executable file made from c++ code, when it finishes it generates another text file which is stored in other blob

it is a very simple operation. But now I would like to receive an email each time the function goes trough successfully, I have searched on the web but the tutorial are very confusing or does not address this simple task.

I did developed the executable file with c++ but I inherited the azure function from someone else and I have zero experience with azure (i am electrical engineer not computer science).  The azure function is written in C#, I just need a guide.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use can add SendGrid output binding to you C# Azure Function. The binding in `function.json` would look something like this:

```
{
    "name": "mail",
    "type": "sendGrid",
    "direction": "out",
    "apiKey" : "MySendGridKey"
}
```

and function body like this:

```
#r "SendGrid"
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

public static void Run(string input, out string yourExistingOutput, out Mail message)
{
    // Do the work you already do

    message = new Mail
    {        
        Subject = "Your Subject"          
    };

    var personalization = new Personalization();
    personalization.AddTo(new Email("recipient@contoso.com"));   

    Content content = new Content
    {
        Type = "text/plain",
        Value = "Email Body"
    };
    message.AddContent(content);
    message.AddPersonalization(personalization);
}
```

Read about [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) and [SendGrid bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem which Mikhail's solution helped me solve. In my case I wanted the static Run method to be asynchronously, which meant I couldn't use the `out` parameter modifier.  My solution's slightly different as it is a timer trigger and was implemented using Visual Studio and the NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extensions.SendGrid v2.1.0.

```
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [TimerTrigger("%TimerInterval%")]TimerInfo myTimer,
        [SendGrid] IAsyncCollector<Mail> messages,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function started execution at: {DateTime.Now}");

        // Do the work you already do...

        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function finished execution at: {DateTime.Now}");

        var message = new Mail();
        message.From = new Email("from@email.com");
        var personalization = new Personalization();
        personalization.AddTo(new Email("to@email.com"));
        personalization.Subject = "Azure Function Executed Succesfully";
        message.AddPersonalization(personalization);

        var content = new Content
        {
            Type = "text/plain",
            Value = $"Function ran at {DateTime.Now}",
        };
        message.AddContent(content);
        await messages.AddAsync(message);
    }
```

This solution used Zain Rivzi's answer to [How can I bind output values to my async Azure Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40409345/5316206)
 and the [SendGrid Web API v3 quick start guide](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp#quick-start).

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be slightly simplified:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

public static class ExtractArchiveBlob
{
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static async Task RunAsync(string input, 
                                      [SendGrid(ApiKey = "SendGridApiKey")] 
                                      IAsyncCollector<SendGridMessage> messageCollector)
    {
            var message = new SendGridMessage();

            message.AddContent("text/plain", "Example content");
            message.SetSubject("Example subject");
            message.SetFrom("from@email.com");
            message.AddTo("to@email.com");

            await messageCollector.AddAsync(message);
   }
}
```

Where `SendGridApiKey` is the app setting holding your Send Grid api key.